# Slow page build time in development with Next.js and TypeScript

Tags: next.js

Created a website using next.js with both backend and frontend in one project.In production it takes so much of time to load a webpage.Next version is 9.3.0.
this is my script.using of scss effects loading time

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node --compiler-options=\"{\\\"module\\\": \\\"commonjs\\\"}\" server/server.ts",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production 'ts-node' --compiler-options=\"{\\\"module\\\": \\\"commonjs\\\"}\" server/server.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are starting your production app using `npm run start`.
From it, it looks like you are running `ts-node` on **production** (which compiles TS on the fly).

It is better to **compile** `server.ts` on `build` step using typescript into `dist` or something like this, then run node on a **js** result inside `dist` folder.

Comment: Had the same issue and this helped speed a lot. I have `server.js` instead of `.ts` but everything else is in `ts/tsx`. Next does already have a loader for these files it seems, so no need for ts-node.

Answer (score 0):

1. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12797#issuecomment-629321790
2. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12797#issuecomment-660225689

For those curious, this was caused by Windows Defender. Windows Defender was delaying the HMR (to do a scan) because our emitted JavaScript files contained the word eval! That's why macOS was unaffected.